# CSV rows to Polyline with OGR

Tags: csv, ogr2ogr

I'm not sure if I can complete this operation in one step - but someone might be able to help me.

My input file is a csv file with **PointID**, **x**, **y**, **z** and **LineID** columns.  I'm looking to combine all rows with the same LineID into Polyline25D using `ogr2ogr` with a virtual datasource (VRT file).

I can get a MultiPoint output, but can't work out how to combine multiple rows (if it's at all possible).

Alternatively, could someone help me with a python script to combine the **x**, **y**, **z** fields into WKT?

Input Example :

```
pointid y   x   z   lineid
1   320589.01   1815258.73  423.78  1
2   320573.49   1815256.71  425.04  1
3   320557.42   1815252.40  425.86  1
4   320541.64   1815248.71  426.19  1
5   320529.37   1815247.01  427.18  1
1   320588.78   1815259.35  423.43  2
2   320573.06   1815257.09  424.66  2
3   320557.00   1815253.09  425.06  2
4   320541.79   1815249.54  425.78  2
5   320529.14   1815247.74  426.22  2
6   320516.78   1815245.02  426.84  2
1   320588.62   1815260.10  423.44  3
2   320572.59   1815258.42  424.65  3
3   320556.21   1815255.29  425.13  3
4   320540.73   1815252.19  425.80  3
5   320529.02   1815248.37  426.20  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Starting with GDAL 2.1, it is possible to directly specify the potential names of the columns that can contain X/longitude and Y/latitude with the X_POSSIBLE_NAMES and Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES open option. (Source: http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html)

It's possible to accomplish this task with the following one-line `ogr2ogr` command (`GDAL >= 2.1`):

```
ogr2ogr multilinestringzs.shp pointzs.csv -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT lineid, ST_Multi(MakeLine(geom)) AS geometry FROM (SELECT lineid, pointid, MakePointZ(x,y,z) AS geom FROM pointzs ORDER BY lineid, pointid) GROUP BY lineid" -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=x -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=y -oo Z_POSSIBLE_NAMES=z -oo KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS=YES
```